# i am trying to put ubunto on a 2tb flash drive how to

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb-drive

hi i have been trying to put Ubuntu on a flash drive and wondering how to do so. i have done the installation setup on one flash drive and set the 2tb flash drive to be the one for the os system to be installed, but it doesnt seem to be working Am i missing something?

oh and i am running it from a flash drive in test mode as well

these are some of the messages i am getting. I am sorry if I am not clear on all things, because really am just trying learn this and so it will take a bit of time for me to understand what some are asking me for again. yes the installer boots correctly so my last question could it be the flash drive itself thats not compatible?

im getting source id  was not found 6x

ubiquity warning source id not found
also get event crtl event beacon loss

Comment: What version of Ubuntu(?) are you trying to install?  Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO? How did you burn the ISO to the install media? Can you boot the install media? What error message or problem(s) do you encounter?  You have to provide more information for us to help you.

Comment: its Ubuntu 22.04 and i can boot on the one flash drive with the iso on it, but when i start to install on the new flash drive, it has messages in the installing boss loss and server things that say not there Sorry, im just trying this out and thought it would be easy and i let it do its thing it seems to have those same messages in the install not sure if i did something or not wrong im not very good with this kinda stuff i have watched a bunch of youtube and they say to just have it on one flash drive but i have followed what it says to do for stand alone and its not working

Comment: so if i update it then do it does that make a difference